# File upload with Jersey : FormDataContentDisposition is null

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm trying to implement file upload with Jersey so I followed this example :
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/
which worked well with an HTML page. Now I adapted it to my application, here is code :

```
  public Response uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail)
    throws IOException {

Response.Status respStatus = Response.Status.OK;

if (fileDetail == null) {
    respStatus = Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
} else {
    try {
    initPath();
    if (fileDetail.getSize() > OntoWebStudioUtil
        .getUploadFileLimit()) {
        respStatus = Response.Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE;
        return Response.status(respStatus).build();
    }

    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, tempDirectory);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    respStatus = Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
return Response.status(respStatus).build();
}
```

But with debug view, once I uploaded my picture and pushed the button send and then get here, uploadedInputStream and fileDetail are null. So I can do nothing... 
I am a beginner with Servlet and then REST, so please be indulgent.

Thank you.

Comment: Please can you also share the <form>...</form> part of the html page?

Comment: Hello, I found why it was not working. In fact it was because my name form was not the same as the FormDataParam (file). 
Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Good to hear you found it. Please can you also post your solution  as an answer to help other users with the same kind of problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found why it wasn't working :
It is because the name you choose after the FormDataParameter("myForm") has to be the same as the name you choosed in your HTML form (name = "myForm")

So,

```
@FormDataParam("myForm") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
@FormDataParam("myform") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail)
```

And the form has to be like

```
    <form action=".../rest/fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p>
    Select a file : <input type="file" name="myForm"/>
   </p>
   <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
</form>
```

Hope it will help some other beginners like me :)