# File upload with Jersey using POSTMAN extension : FormDataContentDisposition is NULL

Tags: web-services, rest, file-upload, jersey, postman

I am getting FormDataContentDisposition object as **NULL** while implementing jersey file upload example as mentioned in below URL :

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/

Here is my sample code,

IMPORTS

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;
```

Rest API code,

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadFiles")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
public Response uploadFiles(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail)
                            throws IOException{
```

> I am getting **fileDetail** object null in above code.

JAR versions used,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

I am hitting my request from **Chrome POSTMAN** Client,

[Here is the snapshot of my request from POSTMAN client...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlwJU.jpg)

I already gone through the link : [File upload with Jersey : FormDataContentDisposition is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083583/file-upload-with-jersey-formdatacontentdisposition-is-null) having same problem but the difference is that I am using REST Client instead of HTML/JSP to submit my request.

Can any one please help me to know why I am getting NULL object of FormDataContentDisposition,

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:

I found the difference between example and my application implementation is that they have below configuration in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and My Application configuration is,

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("/rest")
@javax.ws.rs.Path("application")
public class RestServices extends Application {

        @Override
        public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
            HashSet<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
            classes.add(this.getClass());
            classes.add(RestAPI.class);
            return classes;
        }
```

> Can anybody tell me what is the exact difference between these two
>   configurations. Can Above both implementation will changes the way
>   things working?

Comment: Can you should your import statements?

Comment: @peeskillet - Added imports...

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove @javax.ws.rs.Path("application").
2. You don't need two kinds of Deployment Descriptor, use either Programmatic approach or web.xml;

My approach:

empty web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
    </web-app>
```

and config class:

```
    @ApplicationPath("/rootpath")
    public class YourApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    // Constructor 
    public YourApplication() {
       super (
            //YOUR JAX-RS Service Classes
            MyJaxRSService.class,

            // This one corresponds to jersey-media-json-jackson in dependencies
            JacksonFeature.class, 

            // This is one to : jersey-media-multipart
            MultiPartFeature.class
           );
       }
    }
```

3. update dependencies

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
       <version>2.22.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
       <version>2.22.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
       <version>2.22.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
4. Last and most important: forget such tutorials, it helps you start instantly but when you encounter problem you're stuck, and you'll just waste your time. Instead read official documentation and their real world examples, get some real insight into technology how and why it works.
   Jersey Documentation: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html
   In addition: I'd  recommend this book by Bill Burke - RESTful Java with JAX-RS 2.0.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Cupitor.
I googled about this problem and at that time I found that IBM WebSphere server uses built in JAX-RS by default and we need to set manually if we need to use jersey jars.

As I have not disabled built in JAX-RS via JVM property in my WAS as I was using them too so this problem is still not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am using Jersey 2.22.1, my web.xml has provided configuration for multipart data.

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.xyz.rest.controller;com.xyz.rest.filters</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Reply back if still problem persist